# Tensorflow model doesn't train with multiclassification

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow model trains well with binary image classification. But when i add more categories, the model is stuck at an accuracy of 0.2250. How can I fix this?

Here is all the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1txD7OUSJ1PrFPmm9QEWvc__iuheYprZYjPjPCVnXNTo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is hard to understand without code. Can you post you model definition and training loop ?

Comment: Here is all the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1txD7OUSJ1PrFPmm9QEWvc__iuheYprZYjPjPCVnXNTo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Hugo, please share more what you have tried so far. Just linking externally hosted code is not the way to go on stack overflow.

Comment: Ok, what other information is needed?

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to access your code but here is a amazing tutorial or you can say a kickstart to classification -> [Image classification](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification)

Different models that you can use for classification are listed with the starting code [here](https://keras.io/api/applications/#usage-examples-for-image-classification-models).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does this link work for you? https://docs.google.com/document/d/1txD7OUSJ1PrFPmm9QEWvc__iuheYprZYjPjPCVnXNTo/edit?usp=shar